# Is there a way to measure data traffic from airport extreme?

Tags: network, airport

We have lot of machines and occasionally experience slowness in some devices and wanted to see if it has something do with a device stealing the bandwidth. So I would like to measure the bandwidth utilized by each device.

Of course the other reason is our cable company. But I am afraid there will be revolt if I criticize them.

Answer (score 1):

PeakHour on the Apple Store can use snmp to monitor the bandwidth usage of network routers (including AirPorts). I don't know if can measure individual clients though.

Larger scale you could use something like Cacti to monitor all of your devices and graph their statistics such as open connections, bandwidth, etc.

Comment: I'm trying PeakHour but looks like can't measure individual clients. Only aggregations.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be looking for something like this:

[NetUse Traffic Monitor](http://www.netuseapp.com/)
By Prime73 Inc.

Found on Apple Store.

> NetUse monitors and collects real-time Internet usage stats for all
>   the computers in your home or office that share an Internet
>   connection.
>
> NetUse works great with Apple’s time capsule, airport extreme, airport
>   express (a new version with 802.11n support) or any other brand modern
>   router or a gateway with enabled SNMP function. Please note: The
>   latest Apple Extreme and Time Machine routers that have a tower shape
>   do not support SNMP.

Comment: Found in the AppStore reviews _"There is no way to see what individual device [consumes] (i.e. iMac, Roku box, Apple TV box, cell wifi, etc…) "_ :/

Comment: As of 2020, this app appears to be discontinued. The website is still up (dated 2012), but the link to the AppStore is dead (as are most of the site's links).

Answer (score -2):

This may be a solution but does require purchase of another (fairly cheap) router.
http://www.tmproductions.com/projects-blog/2015/11/8/bandwidth-monitoring

Comment: Please summarize or copy/paste the relevant information from the link into your answer to prevent [link rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot).